# How do I create a list that contains three parts built by regular expression?

Tags: r, regex

So I have a text here, and I would like to separate the texts with three parts: harper_presenter, harper_time and harper_text by using regular expression with R.

The text is: HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]:  When the computer was young, the word hacking was used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the uses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a \"hacker ethic.\"  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic, and does it survive?"

HARPER'S would be harper_presenter, [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.] would be harper_time, and the rest are the harper_text.

It would be best if we do not use exact words to filter.

The actual result would be a list.

Comment: You may not need an actual regular expression, as long as you can assume the presenter name won't contain `[]`: you just need to split on `[` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks Marius, but how can I split on [ and ] ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regular expression to do this you can use the `stringr::str_extract_all` ;

```
text <- "HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]: When the computer was young, the word hacking was used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the uses to which this new technology might be employed. There was even talk of a \"hacker ethic.\" Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal. What is the hacker ethic, and does it survive?"

stringr::str_extract_all(text, "^([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)|(\\[.*\\])|(:.*)")
[[1]]
[1] "HARPER'S"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[2] "[Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[3] ": When the computer was young, the word hacking was used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the uses to which this new technology might be employed. There was even talk of a \"hacker ethic.\" Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal. What is the hacker ethic, and does it survive?"
```

`^([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)|(\\[.*\\])|(:.*)` can be broken into 3 parts separated by the "or" `|` operator.

The first `([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)` says look for a group of one or more Capital letters followed by 0 or more `'`  followed by 0 or more capital letters. The `^` specifies that this needs to  be the start of a line.

The second `(\\[.*\\])` says look for a a group containing 0 or more of anything (`.`) surrounded in square brackets.

The third `(:.*)` says look for a `:` followed by 0 or more anything (`.`)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.  What if I am dealing with more arguments like the texts shown above, and wanting to do the same thing with the texts? @Croote

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand correctly.  Do you want to know how you might do that to a list of text blocks?